# Controlling electrical flow from generator

Tags: generator, power-engineering

I'm working with a factory which has a backup generator which is used during grid instabilities or whenever the factory must disconnect from the grid for maintenance. In these cases, the generator is used instead to maintain operations.

However, I'm investigating whether there's another opportunity in using the generator's excess capacity to sell power on the grid.

*I'll advance now that this question is not concerned with energy-market regulatory or financial viability issues for this idea (I've simplified the context here). The question is whether this is technically feasible.*

The generator would then need to power two separate networks (the factory and the regional network), as seen below.

[image]

I had to create this with Powerpoint due to do the particular setup for the generator, which needs to feed into the two circuits without connecting them with each other (otherwise that'd just be the grid powering the factory, when this is precisely in the case when that's not possible or desirable).

So, this is the first part of the question: is this even possible? **Can a source power two circuits while keeping them isolated from each other?**

Assuming it is possible, we then get to the second part of the question. The generator's primary objective is powering the factory. Whatever is done on the grid is secondary. So the power must satisfy the factory and -- if there's excess capacity on the generator -- then feed into the grid.

Now, my thinking is that the factory has certain power needs (let's assume 1 MW). The generator (let's assume it can generate 1.5 MW) can run at 2/3 capacity and satisfy those needs. However, if the generator is ***also*** connected to the grid and is ramped up to generate it's maximum of 1.5 MW, where will those new electrons go? The resistance of the grid will be effectively infinite (when compared to the factory or the generator), so the natural route would seem to be factory. Which would mean the generator fries the factory's circuit and feeds almost nothing to the grid.

So, is it possible to design a circuit or device (including PIDs, microcontrollers, whatever) such that as much power as needed goes to one circuit, and the excess goes to another?

Comment: What makes you think that the resistance of the grid will be infinite?  Any additional power supplied by the generator above what is required by the factory will go into the grid.  There are synchronization issues and safety issues that have to be worked out if you want to do that.

Comment: @JohnD Well, it's not infinite, but I assume it'd be many orders of magnitude greater than that of my little factory. So that 99% of any power generated above what's needed by the factory will still go through the factory circuit instead of the grid.

Comment: What kind of fuel does your generator run on that it produces energy cheaper than the grid supplies it? Why do you even have a grid connection if this is the case?

Comment: Not at all the case.  The grid is very low impedance, and your factory can't just draw excess power from the generator.  Any power over and above what your factory requires will be absorbed by the grid, similar to how a home solar installation can run the meter backwards if the house is using less energy than the solar inverter is producing.

Comment: @brhans the OP states that the question excludes financial viability, but you're spot on that it will be more expensive than the grid.  Even more so when you consider repair and maintenance on the generator.

Comment: @brhans: For the record, the generator would only operate on the grid in moments of peak demand, when wholesale prices are significantly higher than the generator's operating costs. That opens a whole can of worms of other potential questions or issues you might want to raise, but please stick to the technical feasibility aspects of the question.

Comment: I don't understand why you think you have two unconnected circuits at your generator – it would really just one circuit. There's no "new electrons" here – that's not how electricity works; current always runs in a circle. Your generator's job is to supply energy to the charges that make up that current (energy per charge is voltage). There's no "excess" power – there's just the power you let your generator produce. The grid doesn't have infinite resistance, it has damn near to zero resistance.

Comment: @JohnD: Oh, that does in fact surprise me (it should come as no surprise I'm not an electrical engineer). Interesting. If it's safe to assume that the generator can be easily set up to power the factory and then (and only then) the grid, feel free to write that up as an answer.

Comment: @MarcusMüller: Yes, a simple connection would create a single circuit. But my question was about how to create two independent circuits precisely to avoid the grid from feeding the factory in cases where that's not desirable. And JohnD mentioned the grid's low resistance in a comment above, that did in fact surprise me. And what I meant by "excess power" was power above what was needed by the factory (i.e. the power that should be put on the grid).

Comment: @Wasabi What makes you think you can do that? The motor / generator is a *mechanical* way of transporting power. Whether or not you have electrical connections *doesn't actually matter*. When the generator produces a higher voltage on its grid connection than the grid has, then power flows out of the mechanical momentum that moves that generator. If the generator produces a lower voltage than the grid has, it draws power from the grid, and actually becomes a motor. There's no separation possible here! It's just one source of energy: Movement of some mass.

Comment: @MarcusMüller: That sounds like a great answer to the first part of my question as to whether it is possible to create such a separation. Apparently the answer is no.

Comment: @Wasabi I was too busy, and Transistor wrote an answer in that exact theme already :)

Answer (score 3):

> Can a source power two circuits while keeping them isolated from each other?

Not when running from the same generator but that's not how you would do it anyway.

What you are proposing is quite common in countries with reliable energy supply but where peak demand is on the edge of system capacity. Industrial users with generation capacity can sign up to receive payment for being available for remote start-up and power generation. Going online requires the following operations:

- Start of generator engine. This can be manual or remote or automatic.
- Adjustment of output voltage to match grid voltage.
- Adjustment of frequency to closely match the grid frequency.
- Wait until the voltage between the generator phase and the grid phase drops to zero then close the connecting breaker.
- Now ramp up the generator power.

You are now pushing energy into the grid. Since your load is the closest it will draw the power it requires and the rest feeds into the grid.

> where will those new electrons go?

Forget electrons. They just oscillate back and forth in AC and don't "go" anywhere. Think of current.

> The resistance of the grid will be effectively infinite (when compared to the factory or the generator), ...

Nope. The resistance of the grid is close to zero. That's why the lights don't dim much when you switch on your big loads.

> ... so the natural route would seem to be factory. Which would mean the generator fries the factory's circuit and feeds almost nothing to the grid.

Nope. You'll only need a couple of volts higher than the no-load mains voltage to start exporting power.

[image]

*Figure 1. A synchronisation setup. Source: [CircuitGlobe](https://circuitglobe.com/generator-synchronization.html).*

I did this in college many years ago where we had a machine (the incoming machine of Figure 1) driven by a DC motor. We ramped it up and all three lamps start blinking slowing down as the difference in frequencies gets smaller. When the lamps go out there is no voltage across the contacts so they can be closed without arcing. We then applied power to the DC machine to generate power and feed back to the grid. A following exercise was to reduce the DC machine drive and then switch it into reverse and ramp up the power to act as a brake on the AC machine which then imported power from the grid to act as a motor. It was a most educational experience.

---

See also G59/G10 relays.

> Commonly known in the UK as G59, and as G10 injection testing in the Republic of Ireland, these regulations apply to power plants and generators used for standby and peak lopping application, or grid parallel use.
>
> G59/G10 testing assesses the performance of the mains protection relay that sits between the generator and the electricity grid. It’s not a test of the generator itself. The relay’s purpose is to disconnect or “decouple” the generator from the electricity grid if it detects instability on either side of the connection.

Source: [G59/G10 injection testing](http://www.edina.eu/diesel-generators/diesel-service/g59g10-injection-testing/) by Edina.

Comment: I'd edit out the "electrons" in my answer if they hadn't been quoted here and in the comments. For the record, I know the electrons barely move around, I've just seen that terminology used elsewhere and thought it was interpreted as "cute", not "stupid". Learned two things today! Great answer, btw.

Comment: I recommend you unaccept until the earth has spun around a couple of times to give the whole of humanity a chance to read and answer your question. You'll get some different insights that way and possibly a better answer. Thank you anyway.

Comment: Something just occurred to me. As I mentioned, the generator is mostly used when the factory is momentarily off-grid. So I couldn't "connect" the factory and the regional grid in series, since the factory's meter is offline. Instead, they'd have to be connected in parallel. In this case, would the problem actually be the inverse of what I suggested above? Would the grid's near-zero resistance actually mean most or all of the load would go to the grid instead of the factory? And yeah, I just unaccepted thinking precisely that.

Comment: Read the last paragraph of the G59/G10 relay. It must disconnect if mains fails because you would be trying to power the nation with your little generator and you could electrocute a lineman. You have a few problems with terminology: Connecting the generator and grid in series doesn't make any sense. The energy meter doesn't affect power - it monitors *energy* (power by time). The grid's near zero impedance would present itself as pretty much a short-circuit to your generator. It's circuit breaker should trip with a massive arc.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is certainly possible. It would function just like a grid tied solar power system. When power draw of the factory is less than the gen's capacity, excess power can flow into the grid, and when it exceeds the gen's capacity power will flow from the grid. Whether this is economically viable is another question entirely.